# Can a solid state relay be energized from the same 120V AC source that it switches?

Tags: ac, relay, safety, solid-state-relay, fault

Can a 120V AC input / AC output solid state relay be energized with the same 120V source connected to its contacts?

This can't be done with an electromechanical relay because it generates feedback and you get coil bounce. That was the result of a test I just performed and a subsequent conversation with the manufacture of the 2 NO 2 NC contactor rated for 120V AC coil 400V AC contacts.

I have a specific application where this would be useful. Most of the time the contacts will not pass any current, but in a fault scenario, they will provide critical safety protection, and must be able to pass current delivered from the same source that is energizing the device.

Comment: it can be done with a mechanical relay without any problems.  your description of the task may be incomplete.

Comment: It does like that.  "This can't be done with an electromechanical relay", sure it can.

Comment: SSR and critical safety exclude each other.

Comment: I just tested powering a 120V coil with the same 120V source applied to its contacts and while it appears to work when you only have an open circuit and are measuring contact voltage with a multimeter, it does not work when any load whatsoever is connected to the contacts because that creates coil feedback and coil bounce. I contacted the manufacturer who said you can not do this due to the creation of a feedback loop which generates coil bounce. The 2 NO 2 NC coil and contacts I'm testing are both rated for 120V or above (contacts up to 400V).

Comment: Is it OK what the SSR does not have a coil? It is usually opthotriac.

Comment: @user263983 I was responding to the comments that EM relays can have their coil and contacts wired to the same source, so my response comment was in regards to EM relays, not SSRs.

Comment: @user263983 Thank you! It's always the subject that gets overlooked in the review step. Good catch, sir!

Comment: @BeachInMexico There's a fairly decent [discussion about relays here](https://sound-au.com/articles/relays.htm#s8). It's not a short answer. But it carries a lot of useful information that you may be able to interpret into your situation. I have used AC relays that self-latch, delivering power and using the same power source, themselves. AC relays use *shading*. To quote from the above, *"However unlikely this might seem, it works so well that the AC relay pictured above is almost completely silent, with no chatter at all."*  That's been my experience. But I know nothing of your load.

Comment: @jonk thank you! I'll give that a (long) read. It's good to know you've done what I'm after with an AC self-latch. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a 120V AC input / AC output solid state relay be energized with the same 120V source connected to its contacts?

Yes.

> This can't be done with an electromechanical relay because it generates feedback and you get coil bounce.

There are ways around feedback. Contact bounce is a completely separate issue.

> Most of the time the contacts will not pass any current, but in a fault scenario, they will provide critical safety protection, and must be able to pass current delivered from the same source that is energizing the coil.

Warning bell. SSRs are not safety devices. They are most definitely not critical safety devices. You must assume that it can fail at any time open-circuit or short circuit. You need to re-think this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Are you saying electromechanical relays are inherently safer than SSRs or that relays in general are not safe for use in critical safety systems? What are the best ways around feedback? The manufacturer I called and spoke to about a 2 NO 2 NC 120V coil up to 400V contact stated that you can't power the coil and the contacts with the same source because it creates feedback and coil bounce, so I was looking at SSRs to see if they are any different. Safety is important, and I am only testing, not implement anything. All testing is done safely.

Comment: Nothing is "inherently safer", because " safety " is always referring to a specific kind of failure and associated risks. Now, what Transistor is, IMHO correctly, pointing out is that it seems you're trying to use an SSR as some kind of safety silver bullet. Which it's definitely not. And which it, to the unsuspecting user, might be less than a mechanical relay, but we have literally no way of knowing what "safety" is in your context.

Comment: I was aiming to keep the question simple by not introducing the entire system I'm working on, but I suppose I did mention safety, so the word of caution isn't unwelcome. It's just that EM relays are used in critical safety devices all the time, so I was trying to ascertain if SSRs are never used in critical safety devices based upon his comment. So far I am not finding any corroboration of that assessment, but I'm open to it being true.

Comment: What's a critical safety device to you? In general, I'd assume that is a device that must default to some certain state, very reliably, in case of a system failure like a drastic over-current or -voltage. That's hard to do with SSRs. They're the kind of device you need to protect from such scenarios, because they do not by themselves fail in a reliable state. But that doesn't mean they can't be *part* of a safety-critical system - the system design needs to ensure they're used within operational bounds.